# How do you set the default value of a jQuery DatePicker that is bound with KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, default-value, knockout.js

Using KnockoutJS for a jQuery datepicker found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NAgNV/), I have the following setup:

```html
<span data-bind="text: myDateObject"></span>
<input style="display:none" 
data-bind="enable: enabledBoolean, 
           datepicker: myDateObject, 
           datepickerOptions: { 
              buttonImage: '/Content/calendar.png', 
              buttonImageOnly: true, 
              showOn: 'button', 
              showOtherMonths: true,
              selectOtherMonths: true,
              defaultDate: new Date(), 
              minDate: '-1m',
              maxDate: '+1m'  }" />
```

`myDateObject` is a javascript Date object that could be set to null.  When I click on the calendar image and the datepicker pops up, though, it **always** defaults to the maximum date, even if I have already brought up the datepicker and set a value once already.

As you can see in the code sample above, I'm trying to set the defaultDate to the current date, but it seems to ignore this completely.  Perhaps this is due to the KnockoutJS bindings?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fuRJV/ ?  I don't see the issue.  Also, I just grabbed the first image that I saw to replace your calendar.png :)

Comment: Haha.  That's great.  Functionality is working wonderfully now.  It was the way that data was being formatted for us behind the scenes (via our own KnockoutJS code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being related to how `myDateObject` was being returned back for the datepicker to access.  The custom  `ko.dependentObservable` being accessed was returning the date in a custom format, when it really needed access to the raw data.

To resolve the issue, another `ko.dependentObservable` was created to allow direct access to the raw Date.